# genus of an elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves

I'm trying to show that the curve $f(z,w)=z^4-w^2+1$ has genus 1. The curve is clearly non-singular, so I tried using the degree formula
\begin{equation*}
g=\frac{(d-1)(d-2)}{2}=\frac{3\cdot2}{2}=3,
\end{equation*}
but it should be equal to one. I'm not sure where my error is.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you say it's "clearly nonsingular"? First of all, you don't have an equation yet. Is the curve $f(z,w)=0$? Next, to apply the degree formula, you need the *entire* curve in the projective plane, not just the part in the affine plane. This curve will in fact have a singular point at infinity.

Comment: so the projective curve is $F(Z,W,X) = Z^4-W^2 X^2+X^4= 0$ and the singular point is $(0,1,0)$ ? @TedShifrin

Comment: Yes, the curve is $f(z,w)=0$. Since the only way for $f_z=0$ and $f_w=0$ is for $z=w=0$ and this doesn't hold for $f=0$, the equation is non-singular, right? How do I account for the point at infinity?

Comment: @user1952009: Yes. And, indeed, we see that, setting $W=1$, we have the curve $z^4-x^2+x^4=0$, and this curve has a [tacnode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacnode) at $x=z=0$.

Comment: I see. How can I show that the curve has genus 1 without using the degree formula?

Comment: We have absolutely no idea of what you know and what your context is, @mj_indefinite. I suspect you need to ask the professor who assigned you the exercise.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of doing this. First, review what the genus of a curve is. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2007710/why-is-a-genus-1-curve-smooth-and-is-it-still-true-for-a-non-zero-genus-one-in-g/2009320#2009320) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150840/how-does-one-calculate-genus-of-an-algebraic-curve) question+answers might help. In particular, in the second link, look at the formula of how to adjust the formula $g=(d-1)(d-2)/2$ when there are singularities.

In this particular case, however, I would suggest you find a birational map from $C: w^2=z^4+1$ to a curve of (clearly) genus $1$. For this, look at Theorem 6, page 17, in [this paper](http://alozano.clas.uconn.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/490/2014/01/constrECrank_ALM.pdf) of mine.